# How can I change slick views animation speed?

Tags: 8

I tracked down the variable in slick that changes the animation speed called speed, but I can't seem to change it. In other words, when I change it, it doesn't seem to do anything. I have tried changing it via the browser dev tools, and I tried editing the speed in the slick module. I see that there is Form code to change the speed, but I am not sure where the form is in the UI. Right now the speed to change slides is 3000 and the animation speed is 300. I want to slow down the animation speed.

Comment: Are you using the https://www.drupal.org/project/slick_views module?

Comment: Yes I am using the vanilla setting. I cant remember why, but I think I had to do that in order for me to use a few  customizations.